# How to notify a "higher" class that something in a "lower" class has changed? Or: publish/subscribe the other way round

Tags: c#, events, mvvm, wpf-controls, publish-subscribe

Suppose you have two classes:

```
public class A
{
    int x = 0;
    public void Increase()
    {
        x++;
    }
}

public class B
{
    A a;
    private void DoSomething();
}
```

Is there a way for `B` to be "messaged" and execute `DoSomething()` when anything has changed in `a` (i.e. x has increased)? I know how I could make `a` subscribe to `B`, such that if `B` does `RaiseSomeEvent(..)`, `a` reacts, but not the other way round.

**Background:** I'm trying to create a custom control

```
public class BattleshipCanvas : Canvas
{
    public BSGrid BattleshipGrid {...}
    ...
}
```

that should redraw once anything inside the `BattleshipGrid` (`BSGrid` is a class encapsulating a two-dimensional array) changes, where `BattleshipGrid` will be bound to a certain `BSGrid` in the ViewModel. I thought about adding an event to `BSGrid` that is raised whenever I modify its data, but I don't know how to notify the `BattleshipCanvas` of that event.

I hope I could make it a little clear (it's hard for me to express what I want exactly here) and understandable, but if there arise any questions, feel free to comment and I'll try to answer them. Thanks!

Comment: if you solve it by an event in BSGrid you'll just have to subscribe to that event by using ´BattleshipGrid.MyChangedEvent += BattleshipGridEventHandler(myHandler);´

Comment: A word on terminology of classes: 'higher' and 'lower' are used for classes that are in an inheritance tree, that is if one class is derived from another class. (And the tree is turned upside down: the base is on top so it is the highest and to go to the lower, derived classes is called downcasting ).


But your model composites two classes: One is contained in the other as a member. So you could call them 'contained class' or 'member' and 'containing class' or parent. 


(And no, again OO terminology is sometimes misleading: the parent doesn't refer to inheritance ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for events in c#. In your specific case you may like to make use of the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface. You can use it to inform other classes by events if a property inside the implementing class has changed.
This is also the base to use binding in your project later on.

```
public class A: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Event used to announce a change inside a property of your class
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    int _x = 0;
    public int X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set 
        {
            if (_x != value)
            {
                _x = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("X"); //invokes the event.
            }

        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) //make sure somebody subscribed to the event
            handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); //this calls all eventhandler methods which subscribed to your classes PropertyChanged event.
    }


    public void Increase()
    {
        X++;    //use the property to invoke a property changed event.
    }



}

public class B
{
    A a;

    public B()
    {
        a = new A();
        a.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(a_PropertyChanged);    //subscribe up to the event. (use -= to unsubscribe)
        a.Increase()
    }

    //Catch the event
    void a_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //execute what you would like to do.
        //you can use e.PropertyName to lookup which property has actually changed.
        DoSomething();
    }

    private void DoSomething(){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! I even knew about events and INotifyPropertyChanged, but somehow I thought (1) events in the "lower" class would not come to the surface (which they apparently do, that was dumb of me :)), and (2) that I couldn't add the DoSomething() to a.PropertyChanged because DoSomething() could do stuff that isn't "known" in A. But also this was not smart ;) Thanks very much for the informative example! Seems like I don't get around implementing INPC in the model after all.

Comment: Events are exactly to inform "someobject" you don't know about with information. You don't necessarily need INPC - you can just use any sort of Event to notify of a change in a subclass. Just thought that if you use WPF you might want to also make use of the binding possibilites it offers.

Comment: Yes, binding to a BSGrid (and thus getting away from code-behind towards MVVM) is exactly the reason I wanted to do this in the first place. The only thing that was keeping me from using MVVM was that darn canvas ;-) Hopefully I'll get it to work now.

Answer (score 1):

Events are probably the way to go. You can make any class in your project react to any event being raised in your program, no matter where the event is created/handled.

In your instance, it looks like you don't even need to send over any custom EventArgs.

The most simple example I could find of this is here:

http://timok.tumblr.com/post/57441520214/simplistic-event-example-in-c

Comment: Also thanks to you! Especially the part about any class reacting to any event made things clearer, since I thought they wouldn't be visible to all classes after all.